# Refresh rate won't accept 120 hz

Tags: monitor, xrandr

I can't get my monitor to set the refresh to 120hz. I'm using an nvidia gtx 970. The outputs are below (I'm using a 120 hz monitor & I was able to set it to 120hz in Ubuntu 15.04 when using an AMD graphics card). Now I am using Ubuntu 14.x and it won't let me set it to 120 hz. Please advise.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+  120.0     99.9  
   1440x900      119.9  
   1280x1024     120.0     75.0     60.0  
   1024x768      120.0     75.0     60.0  
   800x600       120.0     75.0     60.3  
   640x480       120.0     75.0     59.9 
$ xrandr -r 120
Rate 120.0 Hz not available for this size
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read about someone else having a similar issue and saw they were doing nvidia settings using

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

I change it on that menu and it worked. How come xrandr doesn't work?

Comment: Is this monitor using DUAL DVI links?  Because if not, then the nvidia app must be lieing to you since a single dvi cable can't handle that refresh rate at that resolution.